# concurrent threads in C programming

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex, condition-variable

I have encountered a problem while implementing wait and signal conditions on multiple threads.

A thread needs to lock a mutex and wait on a condition variable until some other thread signals it. In the meanwhile, another thread locks the same mutex and waits on the same condition variable. Now, the thread which is running concurrently throughout the process signals the condition variable but I want only the first thread that is waiting must be signalled and not the others.

Answer (score 5):

If two threads wait on the same condition variable, they must be prepared to handle the same conditions, or you must carefully construct your program so they are never waiting on the condition variable at the same time.

Why does this notification have to be handled by the first thread and not the second?

You may be better off with two separate condition variables.

Comment: I am not sure about the number of threads as they are created using commands in a script file and each thread has separate functions though they work on the same variable.

Comment: @Swaroop: If the notification has really to be handled by the first thread, you need some kind of queue.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`pthread_cond_signal()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_signal) to wake up one of the threads.

However, more than one might be awoken; this is termed ***spurious wakeup***.  You need a variable to track your application state, as described in the manual page linked above.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is impossible. You say "... I want only the first thread that is waiting must be signalled and not the others." But condition variables never, ever provide any way to ensure a thread isn't signaled. So if you have a requirement that a thread must not be signaled, you cannot use condition variables.

You must always use a condition variable like this:

```
while(NotSupposedToRun)
  pthread_cond_wait(...);
```

So if the thread wakes up when it's not supposed to, the `while` is still `false` and the thread just goes back to sleep. This is **mandatory** because POSIX does not ever provide any guarantee that a thread won't be woken. An implementation is perfectly free to implement `pthread_cond_signal` as a call to `pthread_cond_broadcast` and unblock all threads on every signal if it wants to.

Because condition variables are stateless, the implementation never knows whether a thread is supposed to be woken or not for sure. It is your job to call `pthread_cond_wait` always, and only, when a thread should not be running.

See
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spurious_wakeup
for more details.

If you cannot precisely specify the wakeup conditions for each thread in a `while` loop like the one above, you should not be using condition variables.